# cuSPARSE library calls inside openACC routine

Tags: cuda, gpu, openacc

Is it possible to call the cuSPARSE library from within the routine directive. I have a double for loop on the host that calls for cuSPARSE function that runs on GPU, I am assuming that putting the for loops on the device would help some with performance.

```
    for ( int j = 0; j < nxChunk; j++ )
    {
       for ( int i = 0; i < nyChunk; i++ )
       {            
         #pragma acc parallel 
         setDiag( eig );

        triDiagCusparse( dl, ds, du, tmpMGReal );

         }
      }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The cusparse functions  your code calls don't run on the GPU. They run on the host and internally launch kernels. So no.

Comment: There is no `routine` directive in the code you have shown.  But in any event, just agreeing with @talonmies, cusparse functions are not callable from CUDA device code, nor are they callable from an OpenACC accelerator region, or any OpenACC routine called from an accelerator region, when that accelerator region targets a CUDA GPU.  Currently.

Comment: That was my understanding as well but wanted to get confirmation from more experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenACC *accelerator region* would normally be delineated with the `acc parallel` or `acc kernels` directive.  The OpenACC `routine` directive [is intended to delineate](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/brochures/openacc_sc14.pdf) functions or procedures that might be called from an accelerator region.

The supported features for an accelerator region may vary depending on what type of accelerator the region is or will be targetting.

With respect to accelerator regions that target CUDA GPUs, these regions will be translated by the OpenACC compiler into CUDA device code.  cuSPARSE functions are intended to be called from host code only, and are not callable from CUDA device code.  Therefore they are not usable in an OpenACC accelerator region (or an OpenACC routine that is called from an accelerator region) that targets CUDA devices.